# Exponential generating function and Fibonacci

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, fibonacci-numbers

Consider $F_n$ the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number.

$$g(x) = \sum^\infty_{n=0}F_n \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Prove the following:

$$g''(x)=g'(x)+g(x)$$

I've never dealt with derivatives in the above form so I am not exactly sure where to start with this problem. Would love some help!

Comment: What happens when you compute (formally) both sides of the desired equation?

Comment: @Travis No idea! I don't know how to take the derivative of a sum, or an infinite sum for that matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. One has
$$
g'(x) = \left(\sum^\infty_{n=0}F_n \frac{x^n}{n!}\right)'=\sum^\infty_{n=1}n \times F_n \frac{x^{n-1}}{n!}=\sum^\infty_{n=1}F_n \frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}=\sum^\infty_{n=0}F_{n+1} \frac{x^n}{n!}
$$ 
Can you do the same with $g''(x)$?

Then use $$ F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_n, $$
 to get the announced identity.

Comment: Thanks!! Could you explain why you do not need to take the derivative of $n!$ though?

Comment: Nevermind, I just realized these are all positive integers and 0... So I guess it wouldn't really make sense to take the derivative.

Comment: No derivative, it is rather $\frac{n}{n!}=\frac{n}{n \times (n-1)!}=\frac1{(n-1)!}$.

Comment: Thanks! So then using a similar method to the above am I correct to get $$F''(x) = (F'(x))' = 1 + \sum^\infty_{n=0} F_{n+2} \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Comment: Just $g''(x)=\sum^\infty_{n=0} F_{n+2} \frac{x^n}{n!}$.

Comment: You are welcome!